# Symfony2 DomCrawler remove nodes from DOMElement

Tags: php, dom, symfony

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="body">
   <p>Some text 1</p>
   <h2>Header 2</h2>
   <p>Actual content</p>
</div>
```

I want to get from it everything except `<h2>` so it would look like this:

```
<p>Some text 1</p>
<p>Actual content</p>
```

Trying to achieve this:

```
$crawler = new Crawler( $html );

$body = $crawler->filter( 'div.body' );
$body->rewind();
$body = $body->current();

$h2 = $crawler->filter('h2');
$h2->rewind();
$h2 = $h2->current();

$body->removeChild($h2);
```

But I get:

> [DOMException] Not Found Error

What am I missing?

Comment: Don't know the Symphony implementation, but under normal `DOM` you'd call `$h2->parentNode->removeChild($h2);`

Comment: does `$crawler->filter( 'div.body>*:not(h2)' );` would work ?

Comment: @Wrikken unfortunetly this change occure the same exception

Comment: @Brewal this gives me only first paragraph ("Some text 1") but nothing else, like it stops after finding first h2 :(

Answer (score 7):

As [explained in the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html):

> The DomCrawler component eases DOM navigation for HTML and XML documents.

and also:

> While possible, the DomCrawler component is not designed for manipulation of the DOM or re-dumping HTML/XML.

DomCrawler is designed to extract details from DOM documents rather than modifying them.

**However...**

Since PHP passes objects by reference, and *Crawler* is basically a wrapper for [DOMNode](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php)s, it's technically possible to modify the underlying DOM document:

```php
// will remove all h2 nodes inside .body nodes
$crawler->filter('.body h2')->each(function ($crawler) {
    foreach ($crawler as $node) {
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }
});
```

Here's a working example: https://gist.github.com/jakzal/8dd52d3df9a49c1e5922

Comment: Thanks for the snippet of code, though I think it needs a bit of work. The `$crawler` isn't in scope in the closure, and `$node` is supplied by the iterator as a `Crawler` rather that a `DOMElement`, which I think is what we need. I've got this working [using a foreach](http://pastie.org/10198662) - feel free to use this code in your answer if you wish.

Comment: Ah, just looked at your Gist - will replacing `$node` with a local `$crawler` fix it?

Comment: Yept, sorry for the typo. Updated.

Comment: Thanks Jakub, and no probs.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple ways to do what you need.

**1 Filter by class and P tag**

From your html example you can use the following code:

```
$crawler = new Crawler( $html );

$result = $crawler->filter( 'div.body > p' )->each(
    function (Crawler $node, $i) {
        return $node->text();
    }
);

echo print_r($result, true);
```

notice that the closure return values will be placed in an array. This array will be the $result variable. The return array should look something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Some text 1
    [1] => Actual content
)
```

**2 Get the body and filter each element that you need**

Using the same html you provided, filter only by class and then select each element individually:

```
$crawler = new Crawler( $html );
$body = $crawler->filter( '.body' );
echo $body->filter('p')->eq(0)->text() .'<br />';
echo $body->filter('p')->eq(1)->text() .'<br />';
```

The result should print the content of the P tags

```
Some text 1
Actual content
```

From this code you could get the whole content of a container using the `html` method instead of `text`:

```
$crawler = new Crawler( $html );
$body = $crawler->filter( '.body' );
echo $body->html();
```

You may find the [Node Filtering Reduce](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html#node-filtering) method useful as you can get a domcrawler back with nodes filtered based on custom rules.

Also see [Node Traversing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html#node-traversing) methods to get the nodes that you need after filtering.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of OP)*.

As a workaround, I switched to [`SimpleHtmlDomBundle`](http://knpbundles.com/erivello/SimpleHtmlDomBundle) and fixed my problem in 10 minutes :)